# Advice and plugins against Malware

Tags: plugins, virus

I´m starting with WordPress and would like to make sure my blog stays Malware free. I´ve seen that there are quite a few things to do to insure that.
 Personnally I´d like to keep it easy and still be protected. Is a plugin like Better WP Security good? but it can create some compatibility issues with some plugins
 Or I was thinking of using something like Sitelock that I´ve seen with some hosts.

Or should I use both?
 What would be your advice?
 Thanks a lot for that.

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off topic per the [faq](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4):

WordPress is inherently quite secure software, because of open source, extremely wide installation base and reasonably fast security updates.

There is no such thing as security plugin that magically increases security, while causing no conflicts. Security plugins either act to monitor situation and inform you after the fact (important, but it's not prevention measure) or restrict what can be done to reduce possible attack vectors.

It is most important to make sure all code running is well maintained and audited for security issues and no security plugins are replacement for that.